# Using angular 4 for making just ajax call

Tags: c#, ajax, angular

I want to use Angular 4 for doing small operation like just making ajax call.  Note:  I know, I can use plain jquery to do this... blah... blah...

**Question:**
What Angular 4 Nuget Packages I need to Install for doing small operations like just making ajax call.  Any example will help.

**Technologies I am working with:**  Asp.net MVC, .Net Core, C-Sharp

Answer (score 2):

This would be an inappropriate use of Angular. Angular is a client-side technology whose primary purpose is to provide a single-page application (or SPA) user interface for a Web application.

The idea is that the entire application runs on the client and does not require going back to the server to navigate between the pages of the application. The only time an Angular application needs to hit the server is to get data or to lazy load more of the application.

It makes no sense to use Angular within an MVC application to retrieve data.

Comment: Thank you @Deborahk for replying.  Basically I am not going to use all the capability of angular.  I am still going to use angular 4 for simple viewModel, etc.  All I was trying to understand, how can some add angular library 1 by 1 based on their need.  I don't want to bring all Angular js on page load.  I have watched your courses on pluralsight and they are very easy to understand. Appreciate your good work.  Thanks.